# Science of Potions/Elixirs

Tags: science-based, chemistry

What would the science be behind real-life "magic" potions? What would be a good explanation for their effects?

Comment: I think you should be a little more specific. For instance: What do your potions do?

Comment: @lurch My potions would be mostly temporary increases in physical abilities

Comment: For real-life examples, you can check [Performance-enhancing substances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance-enhancing_substance)

Comment: I'm afraid this question is far too broad.  All possible potions?  Invent ingredients without context of your world?  Even if narrowed to just endurance-enhancing potions, how do I know to suggest powdered Oak with an appropriate spell or [Erythropoietin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythropoietin)?  Please help us out by providing information about the nature of your world, how magic is expressed, what the potions should do, etc.

Comment: @Alexander I'm looking more towards temporary and consumable

Comment: I'm not sure how a potion/elixir differs from modern medicine. What is the difference between a potion that treats a cold and liquid cold medicine? I think we need a little more detail here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tuffy, but here are my thoughts:

Let's take something like adrenaline to start. 
**What does it really do?** Adrenaline, aka epinephrine increases blood flow to muscles, output of the heart, pupil dilation, and blood sugar.
 **How does it work?** It binds alpha and beta receptors (G-proteins found in many cells).

Now let's look at morphine, **how is it capable of "muting" the feeling of pain or most things for that matter?** Similar to G-proteins it affects receptors within the immune system, in fact it affects a tonne of different parts of the immune system. But the good news is that WHO (world health org) states it's the safest needed drug in the medical field. Not to mention it's produced naturally from poppy flowers (opium).

Now something from Sci-Fi+Sci-Fact, Black Goo. I like the idea of both black goo and nanobots due to their ability to be virus like. However you want enhanced abilities. Sure thing, you get vitamin K from the bacteria in your gut, so why can't you drink some robots or alien bacteria that improves your vision or hearing for a short while? Nanobots can self terminate to avoid using too many resources and the alien bacteria is eventually destroyed by your immune system after a day.

I'm no biologist but creativity isn't much to ask for. Finally, Adrenaline in some advanced form could likely compete with Nanobots on the level of attribute improvements you would receive. Morphine could be a template for an advanced resistance / tolerance "potion" and black goo stretches as far as your imagination can let aliens be awesome.